# What is the Secondary Entity in the MS CRM Registration Tool?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

When registering a plugin step with the registration tool, there is option for "Secondary Entity".  What is a Secondary Entity, and in what scenario would a CRM developer can use this option?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Secondary entity is used for SetRelated and RemoveRelated messages, otherwise it should be null.

Secondary entity is child is the related entity of primary entity. Secondary Entity should used only when you want to trigger plugin for an event requiring two entities like the "SetRelated" message.

Please have look here: [Link](http://tomtajic.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/crm-2011-plugin-registration-primary.html)

Comment: could you share uses of SetRelated and RemoveRelated messages ?

Comment: @KumarManish I can't find any example online. But in free time I will write an example and will share with you.

Comment: Thanks for spending valuable time, if you found good example , please share with me

Comment: @KumarManish no problem, I will share with you.